# Highscore Form to Form data transfer

Tags: c#, forms, transfer

I'm making a simple game where you fly the ship around, dodging asteroids until they hit you and you blow up. I have a form for the game, and then when you get hit after 5 seconds (I'm using a timer) it will tick closing that form and opening a new form (EndGameForm). I'll show my code, but there seems to be a failure and my knowledge in C# is very limited.

```
private void GameEndTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.Visible = false;
        EndGameForm gform = new EndGameForm();
        gform.Show();
        GameEndTimer.Enabled = false;
        var frm2 = new EndGameForm(ScoreLabel.Text.ToString());
        frm2.Show();
}
```

That was in the first form, saving the text from the score label and opening the new form.

```
public EndGameForm(string s)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        Score1Label.Text = s;
}
```

That was in the second form, recalling the save and setting the new Highscore label.

> Error Code: Error 1   'SemesterProject.EndGameForm' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes 0 arguments    \HHS-FS2\Home$\Students\10th
>   Grade\985832\CP
>   C#\SemesterProject\SemesterProject\GameForm.cs    82  33  SemesterProject

Comment: The error is self-explanatory... You've passed a `string` as argument to constructor declaration of the `EndGameForm` class. But within its calling, no argument has been passed into...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass something to constructor of the `EndgameForm` class, as it is supposed to be based on your design.

As a rule of thumb, that could be done by a string field class from the caller class:

```
private string _tobeSentAsArgument {get; set;}
```

after its initialization where ever you want, it is ready to be used:

```
private void GameEndTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    EndGameForm gform = new EndGameForm(this._tobeSentAsArgument);
    gform.Show();
    GameEndTimer.Enabled = false;
    var frm2 = new EndGameForm(ScoreLabel.Text.ToString());
    frm2.Show();
}
```